# I'm facing valueError in my nth fibonacci number code

Tags: python, data-structures, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I'm facing valueError in my nth fibonacci number code  on CodingNinjas compiler, when I ran it on repl.it, it showed the answers correctly. Can anyone help me figure out the issue with this code?

```
def fibonacciNumber(n):
    # Write your code here.
    list_ = [0,1]
    
    if n == 0:
        print(list_[0])
    elif n == 1:
        print(list_[1])
    else:
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            newval = list_[i-1] + list_[i-2]
            list_.append(newval)
            
        print(list_[-1])
    
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    number = int(input())
    fibonacciNumber(number)
```

[image: Error]

It might be due to my approach. If anyone can suggest how can I optimize the code a bit, it'll be a great help

Comment: The error indicates that the code is trying to read a number from the input, when there is no more number there -- the error has nothing to do with your Fibonacci function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thank you Chris for pointing it out. I'll do it properly from now on